# How to include a view.blade.php file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this file `sidebar.blade.php` inside views/content, I want to include this (`sidebar.blade.php`) file to my views `home.blade.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures)?

> Blade's @include directive, allows you to easily include a Blade view
>   from within an existing view. All variables that are available to the
>   parent view will be made available to the included view:

```
@include('shared.errors')
```

> Even though the included view will inherit all data available in the
>   parent view, you may also pass an array of extra data to the included
>   view:

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Comment: Check the link I provided to the documentation, it is extremely helpful. By default, Laravel will automatically be looking in the `view` directory, so you can leave that out of the `@include()` function. Based on your question, it would likely be `@include('content.sidebar')`.